# Ошибка в "Народу сбежались бездна"?

Tags: егэ, грамматика

Решаю билеты по ЕГЭ. Вопрос такой: определить ошибку в предложении

> Народу сбежались бездна.

Я дал ответ *нарушение связи между подлежащим и сказуемым* -- неправильно. Оказалось, что правильный ответ: "нарушение порядка слов".

Это ошибка в билете? Я думаю, что при любом порядке слов, форма глагола неверна -- должно быть *сбежалось* или что-то другое.

Comment: Где Вы нашли этот тест? В КИМах ЕГЭ 2015 года это задание №7. Всего 7 типов грамматических ошибок нужно уметь определить, и нарушения порядка слов среди нет, да и  и быть не может, так как в русском языке нет строгих правил на этот счет. Пользуйтесь КИМами от разработчиков ЕГЭ, например, сборником под ред. И.П. Цыбулько.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В единственном числе ставится сказуемое при существительных со значением неопределенного количества (масса, уйма, бездна, пропасть и т.п.). 
– Дел у него была бездна... (Чернышевский)
Кстати, ваш пример взят у Толстого. Народу сбежалось бездна... (Л. Толстой)

> Ваш ответ верный!

Дополнение

Постановка сказуемого во множественном числе предпочтительна при наличии следующих условий:

> 1)      если главные члены предложения оторваны друг от друга, например: Большинство участников совещания на предварительном обсуждении проекта нового положения о жилищно-строительной кооперации выразили свое согласие с основными его принципами; ряд делегатов от разных организаций предлагали изложить порядок работы комиссии;
>
> 2)      если при препозитивном подлежащем (стоящем впереди сказуемого) имеется причастный оборот или определительное придаточное предложение с союзным словом который, причем причастие или слово который стоит во множественном числе, например: Большинство студентов первого курса, поступивших в вузы непосредственно по окончании средней школы, успешно сдали зимнюю экзаменационную сессию; Большинство учебников, которые были изданы в этом году, получили высокую оценку специалистов; Ряд лиц, виденных Белътовым, не выходили у него из головы (Герцен);
>
> 3)      если при собирательном существительном имеется несколько управляемых слов в форме родительного падежа множественного числа, что усиливает представление о множественности производителей действия, например: Большинство прогрессивных общественных деятелей, писателей, ученых во всем мире выступают за сближение народов, их культур; Большая часть моих привычек и вкусов не нравились ему (Л.Толстой);
>
> 4)      если при подлежащем имеются однородные сказуемые, например: Большинство заочников своевременно выполнили все контрольные работы, успешно сдали зачеты и хорошо подготовились к экзаменам.
>
> 5)      если подчеркивается активность и раздельность действия каждого действующего лица, например: Ряд сотрудников отдела заявили, что они не согласны с позицией администрации; но: Ряд вопросов, стоявших на повестке дня, за недостатком времени не обсуждался (подлежащее обозначает неодушевленный предмет). Поэтому сказуемое в страдательном обороте обычно ставится в единственном числе, так как подлежащее обозначает объект действия, а не его субъект, например: Большинство участников соревнований размещено в пансионатах; Ряд молодых бизнесменов направлен за рубеж;
>
> 6)      при обратном согласовании, если именная часть составного сказуемого имеет форму множественного числа, например: Большинство представленных на конференции стран стали участниками крупного научного форума; Ряд спортсменов нашего учреждения стали призерами городских соревнований. Такая форма согласования обычна для сказуемых, выраженных краткой формой прилагательного или относительным прилагательным, например: Целый ряд сцен в пьесе правдивы и интересны; Большая часть домов на нашей улице панельные. Ср.: Большинство людей, встретившихся мне здесь, были оборванные и полураздетые... (Л. Толстой); ...Большинство дверей были низки для его роста (Л.Андреев).

Как видно, ни одно из этих условий нет в вашем варианте. К тому же есть бесспорный вариант, указанный в параграфе 184, который уже привел Александр.

Comment: Хотя,наварное, ответ в тестах правильный. Ведь действительно здесь нарушение порядка слов. Ср.: Бездна народу сбежалось. 

Но при такой форме сказуемого. ваш ответ тоже не может считаться ошибкой!

Answer (score 1):

Я усматриваю ошибку в несогласованности множественного числа сказуемого с другими членами предложения.

(В порядке обсуждения возможности здесь мн. числа сказуемого, по справочнику Розенталя: http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm )

1.*"Сказуемое может стоять во множественном числе при так называемом обратном согласовании... с именной частью составного сказуемого"* (§183 п.2)

Но в нашей законченной фразе отсутствует сам объект обратного согласования и непросто его пристроить, расширив фразу. "Бездна народу сбежались зеваками"?

2.*"Согласование по смыслу."* (п.3)

В приведённых Розенталем примерах (*Еще недавно большинство представленных на конференции стран не имели возможности участвовать в таком форуме; Ряд сотрудников отдела заявили, что они не согласны с мнением администрации; Часть лунных образцов напоминают по своему составу камни, обнаруженные на Земле близ старых вулканов.*) "согласующий" смысл держится на том, что составные понятия (ряд сотрудников, большинство стран, часть образцов) подразумевают во множественном числе счётные существительные, входящие в их состав (сотрудники, страны, образцы). А в нашем случае нет "народов": "по смыслу" можно говорить о таковом лишь в единственном числе.

Остаются варианты:

Народу сбежал**о**сь бездна.(= Сбежал**о**сь бездна народу.)

Народу сбежал**а**сь бездна. (= Бездна народу сбежал**а**сь.)

(**P.S.** Уточнил предпочтительные варианты с альтернативным порядком слов, по §184 п.14)

Comment: Значит, ответ "нарушение связи между подлежащим и сказуемым"? Но ведь его признали неверным. Автор и спрашивает, почему неверно, а Вы доказываете, что верно. Ему от этого не легче. Он хочет понять свою ошибку.

Comment: Вы правильно объяснили логику составителей - видимо, они руководствовались источником, близким к этому. Но я бы не смог представить себе такое необычное выражение (будь оно верным), даже выбирая ответ из вариантов. Сложновато и для школьника обратить на такую возможность внимание при том, что напрашивается иной способ исправления.

Answer (score 0):

Это что за тесты по ЕГЭ? Не видела таких. Как на олимпиаде.

Ключ к тесту верен.  Дело в том, что по правилам возможно и ед., и множ. число, это не ошибка, но только не в таком порядке. http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm   
§183.

При подлежащем, имеющем в своем составе собирательное существительное с количественным значением, сказуемое может стоять в единственном числе (грамматическое согласование) и во множественном числе (согласование по смыслу).
Сказуемое может стоять во множественном числе при так называемом обратном согласовании, т.е. согласовании связки не с подлежащим, а с именной частью составного сказуемого, например: большинство группы были приезжие.

Если бы было "бездна народу сбежались на..." - это не ошибка. А вот "Народу сбежались бездна" - ошибка. Здесь только в ед. числе, а вот род может быть и женск., и  средний, потому что связь со всем неопределённым счётным оборотом - смысловая, а со словом "бездна" - грамматическая.

Comment: Людмила писала: Если бы было "бездна народу сбежались на..." - это не ошибка.

===
Но это же как-то надо обосновать! У Розенталя ведь совсем другое: "В ЕДИНСТВЕННОМ числе ставится сказуемое при существительных со значением неопределенного количества (масса, уйма, БЕЗДНА, пропасть и т.п.)".

Comment: А я вам чьё правило процитировала? Это и есть Розенталь.

Comment: Розенталь всё же предпочёл сочетание с "бездной" привести не в 183-м параграфе, который Вы процитировали, а оговорить отдельно.  

См. http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm , § 184, п. 14.

Comment: Разумеется, у него своя цель, у меня своя. Мне нужно было правило, чтобы прокомментиовать ответ в ключах к ЕГЭ.

Comment: Людмила, и все же вряд ли можно сказать: Бездна народу сбежалось! Под народом имеется в виду совокупность людей, а не отдельные люди!

Comment: Вот именно:совокупность, значит, сбежалось(по смыслу) и сбежалась(грамматическая связь), сами и подтвердили, что "-ись" ошибка,но в ЕГЭ имелось в виду,что смысловая связь была бы вариативной(не ошибкой) при другом порядке слов.

Comment: Да, Людмила, можно и сбежалось и сбежалась! Но не Сбежал**ись**.  ЕГЭ именно так - мн.ч. Ошибка не ответах ЕГЭ, а в самом предложении: Народу сбежал**ись** бездна.

Обратите внимание на мн.ч. Кстати, в самом ответ я самом начале сказал, что в ответах правильный вариант! Но и автор вопроса прав!

Comment: И я о том,  с Вами я не спорю, больше с Александром.Таких тонкостей ученику знать не обязательно. Достаточно, что увидел неверное согласование. Но если в вариантах ответа было нарушение порядка слов - ученик должен был это увидеть, потому что это первично, в согласовании же есть возможность написания  во множ. числе. Но это уже "выкомаривание" создателей вопросов. Не Цыбулько, случаем?

Comment: Не знаю. Мне такой вопрос попадается впервые!

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: Народу сбежалось бездна. Порядок слов здесь правильный, но нарушена сочетаемость.

Об этом можно узнать из толкового словаря, в котором приводится этот пример:
БЕЗДНА кого-чего. Разг. Огромное количество, множество. Там б. цветов. Народу сбежалось - б. У меня б. дел. Б. премудрости (ирон.).

О СОЧЕТАЕМОСТИ

1)При прямом порядке слов сочетаемость в  ж.р. (как в двусоставном предложении): "В голову мою набралась вдруг такая бездна мыслей (Л.Н. Толстой).

2) При обратном порядке слов сочетаемость в  ср.р. (как в безличном предложении): "Слушай, ― начал он повелительно, ― публики сегодня приходило целая бездна" (Ф. М. Достоевский).

О ПОРЯДКЕ СЛОВ

Порядок слов может быть прямым и обратным. Форма Р.п. выносится на первое место с целью актуализации, в этом случае на это слово падает логическое ударение. Вообще говоря, перестановка слов всегда меняет расстановку ударений и смысловые акценты, с этой целью она и применяется.

Comment: Вера, Вы вопрос читали? Вас не спрашивают, как правильно (Уже Толстой написал), Вас спрашивают, КАК КЛАССИФИЦИРОВАТЬ ошибку, почему неверен ответ "нарушение связи между подлежащим и сказуемым".

Comment: Вера, по Розенталю (§185, п. 14) возможен и второй вариант:

Дел у него была бездна... (Чернышевский).

/Народу сбежалась бездна./

Упоминается о тенденции выбора между тем и другим родом в случае иных позиций сказуемого (смещённость к началу - средний род, к концу - согласуется с существительным).

Comment: Еще от ударения зависит: НарОду  сбежалось (пауза) бездна. Но: Народу сбежалась бЕздна. Поэтому в словаре и поставлено авторское тире. Оно  разделяет подлежащее и сказуемое, поэтому грамматическое согласование между ними отсутствует.